# Progress bar and auto page refresh in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am new to ruby on rails. I am building an app that use Autodesk view and Data API to view files in the SHOW view. Processing each file takes time and so, when a user clicks the show link next to the file name, it takes a while for the browser to move to the view to the point that a user thinks that the show link is not responding. 
What is the simplest way to show a progress bar of the process when clicking on the show link?
Also, when the show page appears, I need to refresh the page for the drawing to start showing in the view. How can I auto refresh the page for one time?

Comment: JQuery's ProgressBar (set to indeterminate) will keep your users from freaking out. JavaScript has a `reload` function you can use to reload a page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should follow the github repository code for this https://github.com/caarlos0/nprogress-rails.

I hope it'll help you..

Answer (score 0):

You asked for a simplest way, there you are: https://github.com/caarlos0/nprogress-rails

This gem will include nprogress to your application, please read the manual at the link above, notice if you are using Turbolink or not to setup it proper.

> You basically have to add the requires to the application.js file:
>
> ```
> //= require nprogress
> //= require nprogress-turbolinks
> ```
>
> The nprogress-turbolinks is required only if you use turbolinks.
>
> Also, into your application.css.scss file:
>
> ```
> *= require nprogress
> *= require nprogress-bootstrap
> ```
>
> The nprogress-bootstrap is required if you use bootstrap and have a
>   fixed toolbar or anything else. tl;dr: if the console shows no errors,
>   but the progress doesn't appear, try this.